# Como ler e imprimir uma palavra inteira em C++

Tags: c, c++

Bom, fiz esse programinha aí em c++ para faculdade. Agora não sei como **ler no terminal e depois imprimir**, lá na função imprime, **uma palavra inteira!**

Até então eu estava usando a biblioteca `<string>` só que nesse caso quando passo por paramento da aquele erro de segmentação. Tentei também usar `char texto[100]`, scanf() e printf() nesses casos não dá erro mas também não imprime nada.

Se der para mostrar como ler os espaços também seria legal kkk

*Deixo já meus agradecimentos, valeu aí a atenção* ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct no {
    int id;
    char codprod;
    double preco;
    int quant;
    struct no* prox;
};
typedef struct no No;

struct lista {
    No *inicio;
    No *fim;
};  
typedef struct lista Lista;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void inicia(Lista* L){
    L->inicio = L->fim = NULL;
}

void insere_fim(Lista* L, int _id, char _codprod, double _preco, int _quant){
  No* no;
  no = (No*) malloc(sizeof(No)); 

  no->id = _id;
  no->codprod = _codprod;
  no->preco = _preco;
  no->quant = _quant;

  no->prox = NULL; 
  
  if(L->inicio == NULL){
    L->inicio = L->fim = no;
  }else{ 
    (L->fim)->prox = no;
    L->fim = no;
  }
}

int remove_fim(Lista *L) {
    No *nofinal, *noanterior;
    int id;                     
    if (L->inicio == NULL)
        return -1;          
    nofinal = L->inicio;
    while (nofinal != L->fim){
        noanterior = nofinal;
        nofinal = nofinal->prox;
    } 
     
    if(L->inicio == L->fim) 
        L->inicio = L->fim = NULL; 
    else{
        id = nofinal->id;
        nofinal = NULL;
        noanterior->prox = NULL; 
        L->fim = noanterior;
    }
    free(nofinal);
    return id;
}

int sup = 0;
void aplica_desc_e_quant_sup(Lista *L, int _desc){
    int count = 0;
    No* no;
    no = L->inicio;
    while(no != NULL){

        no->preco -= (no->preco / 100) * _desc;

        if (no->quant > 500) sup++;

        no = no->prox;
        count++;
    }
}

void imprime(Lista *L){
    int count = 0;
    No* no;
    no = L->inicio;
    while(no != NULL){

        cout << endl << "codigo do produto: " << no->codprod;
        cout << endl << "novo valor: " << no->preco << endl;

        no = no->prox;
        count++;
    }
}
    
void apaga(Lista* L){
    int r = 0;
    while (r != -1)
    {
        r = remove_fim(L);
    }
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main() {

  int id, quant, desc;
  char codprod;
  double preco;

    Lista L;
    inicia(&L);
    printf("\t\t--------1. Programa que Cadastra 5 Produtos--------\n\n");

    
    for (id = 0; id < 5; id++) {

        cout << endl << "----- Produto [" << id << "] -----" << endl;

        cout << endl << "codigo do produto: ";
        cin >> codprod;

        cout << endl << "preco: ";
        cin >> preco;

        cout << endl << "quantidade: ";
        cin >> quant;

        cout << endl << "------------------------------" << endl;
        
        insere_fim(&L, id, codprod, preco, quant);
    }

    cout << endl << "taxa de desconto: %";
    cin >> desc;

    aplica_desc_e_quant_sup(&L, desc);

    printf("\t\t--------- RELATORIO --------\n\n");

    imprime(&L);

    cout << endl << "Quantidade de produtos com quantidade estocada superior a 500: " << sup << endl;

    apaga(&L);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma padrão de ler da `stdin` é mesmo com a biblioteca `<string>`:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    std::string variavel;
    std::cin >> variavel;
    std::cout << "Você digitou: " << variavel << std::endl;
}
```

Sobre o problema com a passagem de parâmetro, acho que faz mais sentido em uma nova pergunta.